# assign value to a text box from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In the form, I have put a textbox and a button as:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtCustomerId" placeholder="Customer ID">
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#LovCustomer"><i class="fa fa-list"></i></button>
</span>
```

when this button is pressed, a modal form (bootstrap) is popped up. I have placed a button on the modal form as:

```
<td><button id="LSSL" value="LSSL" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button></td>
```

I have below jQuery in `<head>`:

```
$(function(){
    $('#LSSL').click(function(){
        $('#txtCustomerId').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

My requirement is to obtain the value of the button being pressed (in the modal form) and assign it to the txtCustomerId of the parent form. But when I press the button, page gets refreshed and the text filed is blank (since it is refreshed).

I think the value is assigned but since the page is refreshed, assigned value vanishes.

I would like to know either to stop the page refresh or any other way of getting this achieved.

Thanks in advance.

Below is my `<head>` section for your reference:

```
<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('button').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var value = $(this).val();
                $('#txtCustomerId').val(value);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button should be like this,

```
<td><button type="button" id="LSSL" value="LSSL" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button></td>
```

And in Js part, you can do `preventDefault()`,

```
$(function(){
   $('#LSSL').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var value = $(this).attr('value');
       $('#txtCustomerId').val(value);
   });
});

//You can also use $(document).ready(function(){}) as well.
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#LSSL').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var value = $(this).attr('value');
       $('#txtCustomerId').val(value);
   });
});
```

Comment: with `e.preventDefault();` the page doesn't get refreshed. (Y)

But the value doesn't get assigned to the textbox.

Comment: Updated my answer @LakmalPremaratne

Comment: If the top method will not work, try using the same with `$(document).ready(function()`. @LakmalPremaratne

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`preventDefault()` to stop the default behavior of button

```
$(function(){
   $('#LSSL').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       alert($(this).val());
   });
});
```

**or** use

```
<input id="LSSL" type="button" value="Click" onclick="doSomething(this)">

function doSomething(obj) {
alert(obj.value);
}
```